# Flutter App - FCM - Android not sending Notifications

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I have stepped through all the steps here twice over. 
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/firebase_messaging

I even deleted and re-paired my android package with FCM.

I have the right intent added to the manifest xml... and double checked it.

[image: fcm test screen screenshot]

I have tried both on my Android Emulator, and my Actual Google Pixel.

I don't ever see an android notification.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

I'm using 
Android Version - 9.0 (Pie) - API 28
Emulator Version - 28.0.16-5112988

It's a fresh emulator.

[EDIT]
I am now able to get notifications to my actual Google Pixel, but still not the emulator.

Thank you.